# How to find a solution in terms of vars which satisfies equation for any value of x?

Tags: equation-solving

I am porting some Maple code I wrote to Mathematica. In one place, I use Maple's solve with    what Maple call, identity.

The help page for this command is [here](https://de.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=solve/identity&term=solve/identity)

[image]

What is Mathematica's equivalent of the above command?  I will show below 3 examples of its use.   Basically what it does, is that given one equation, with functions in it that depends on $x$, it tries to solve for the unknowns in the equation by comparing coefficients.

For example, given

```
  eq=c1*(x^2+x)+c2*(2+2*x)+c3==-4*x^2+2*x+6
```

and asking it to solve for `c1,c2,c3` it should give the solution `{c1 = -4, c2 = 3, c3 = 0}`

And given

```
eq = -4*c1*Sin[2*x] + 4*c2*Cos[2*x] + 2*c3*Cos[2*x] - 
    8*c3*x*Sin[2*x] + 2*c4*Sin[2*x] + 8*c4*x*Cos[2*x] == 3*x*Cos[2*x];
```

and asking it to solve for `c1,c2,c3,c4` it should give the solution

```
{c1 = 3/16, c2 = 0, c3 = 0, c4 = 3/8}
```

And given

```
eq = -3*c1*Exp[-x] + Cos[x]*(-3*c2 - c3) + Sin[x]*(-3*c3 + c2) == 
  Exp[-x] + 2*Cos[x]
```

and asking it to solve for `c1,c2,c3` it should give the solution

```
{c1 = -1/3, c2 = -3/5, c3 = -1/5}
```

By hand, this is done by "comparing" coefficients. In computer algebra, there are specialized algorithms to do this, but I have not found which command or combination of commands in Mathematica that could do this.

Any suggestions?

Screen shot from Maple for illustration
[image]

I am using Mathematica Version 12.3.1

Comment: Have you tried `SolveAlways`?

Comment: @JimB Yes, that was the first command I tried.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITY1V.png)

Comment: That works for your first example.  But it hasn't completed yet (after a few minutes) for the other two examples.  Am I just not seeing `SolveAlways` mentioned in your question?

Comment: @JimB I said `but I have not found which command or combination of commands in Mathematica that could do this`. I did not list each attempt I made.

Comment: But it should be `SolveAlways[eq, x]` rather than `SolveAlways[eq, {c1,c2,c3}]`.

Comment: @JimB  I need to solve for the unknowns $c_i$. Not for $x$ But I also tried for $x$, and so far, no answer.

Comment: `SolveAlways[c3 + c2 (2 + 2 x) + c1 (x + x^2) == 6 + 2 x - 4 x^2, x]` results in `{{c1 -> -4, c2 -> 3, c3 -> 0}}`.  *Mathematica* figures the remaining variables are the ones for which to be solved.

Comment: @JimB  OK, will use $x$. But it works on one example (the polynomial), and for the others , it seems to take very long time. But will try and wait and see if it can solve it. In Maple, this is solved instantly.

Comment: @JimB I had to terminate it after 3 hrs. `SolveAlways` clearly is not working for all cases. So need to find if there is alternative that works for all cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$,then $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(0)=g'(0),f''(x)=g''(0)$ etc. We use this to get several equations.

```
expr1 = -4*c1*Sin[2*x] + 4*c2*Cos[2*x] + 2*c3*Cos[2*x] - 
  8*c3*x*Sin[2*x] + 2*c4*Sin[2*x] + 8*c4*x*Cos[2*x]; expr2 = 
 3*x*Cos[2*x];
sol = Solve[{expr1 == expr2, D[expr2, x] == D[expr1, x], 
    D[expr2, {x, 2}] == D[expr1, {x, 2}], 
    D[expr2, {x, 3}] == D[expr1, {x, 3}]} /. x -> 0, {c1, c2, c3, c4},
   Reals]
expr1 == expr2 /. sol[[1]] // Simplify
```

> `{{c1 -> 3/16, c2 -> 0, c3 -> 0, c4 -> 3/8}}`

> `True`

```
f = -3*c1*Exp[-x] + Cos[x]*(-3*c2 - c3) + Sin[x]*(-3*c3 + c2);
g = Exp[-x] + 2*Cos[x];
sol = Solve[{f == g, D[f, x] == D[g, x], D[f, {x, 2}] == D[g, {x, 2}]} /. x -> 0]
f == g /. sol[[1]]
```

> `{{c1 -> -(1/3), c2 -> -(3/5), c3 -> -(1/5)}}`

> `True`

Comment: Thanks. So is it enough to take only three derivatives each time, regardless of what `f` and `g` are and the number of constants $c_i$? I need to test this on more cases to see if it works on all what I have. good method.

Comment: for $n$ constants,we need to use the order of the derivative from $0$ to $n-1$.

Comment: Ok, but then why in the first example you show, which has 4 constants, you did up to third derivative, but in the second example, which had 3 constants, you also did up to 3rd derivative? That is why I asked. It looks like second example only needs up to 2nd derivative, and I tried it now and it worked.

Comment: @Nasser Sorry, it's my mistake. Only need up to  second order derivative.

Comment: `SolveAlways[
 Normal@Series[expr1, {x, 0, 3}] == Normal@Series[expr2, {x, 0, 3}],
  x]`

Comment: `ForAll[x, 
 Normal@Series[expr1, {x, 0, 3}] == Normal@Series[expr2, {x, 0, 3}] //
   Evaluate]
Resolve[%, Reals]`

Comment: Sorry, @cvgmt , your method does not work for all possible expressions. You say: "for n constants,we need to use the order of the derivative from 0 to n−1. " .......Let me give a counterexample with two constants. `expr1 = a/3 x^3;
expr2 = b/2 x^2;
Solve[{expr1 == expr2, D[expr2, x] == D[expr1, x]} /. x -> 0, {a, 
  b}, Reals] ` gives `{{}} `, means full set of solutions for a,b. But `expr1 == expr2 /. {a -> RandomReal[], b -> RandomReal[]} /. 
 x -> RandomReal[] `for any a,b,x  yields `False `.

Comment: @Akku14 `expr1 = a/3 x^3; expr2 = 
 b/2 x^2; Solve[{expr1 == expr2, D[expr2, x] == D[expr1, x]} /. 
  x -> 1, {a, b}, Reals]` for example.

Comment: to @cvgmt  next counterexample for x->1  `expr1 = a (x - 1)^3; expr2 = 
 b (x - 1)^2; Solve[{expr1 == expr2, D[expr2, x] == D[expr1, x]} /. 
  x -> 1, {a, b}, Reals] ` yields again `{{}} `  ...... That means in order to be shure, you have to test for x-> all possible values.

Comment: @Akku14 `expr1 = a/3 x^3; expr2 = b/2 x^2;
ForAll[x0, 
  Normal@Series[expr1, {x, x0, 2}] == 
   Normal@Series[expr2, {x, x0, 2}]];
Resolve[%]`

Answer (score 2):

Another simple way is helping SolveAlways a little

```
expr1 = -4*c1*Sin[2*x] + 4*c2*Cos[2*x] + 2*c3*Cos[2*x] - 
        8*c3*x*Sin[2*x] + 2*c4*Sin[2*x] + 8*c4*x*Cos[2*x]; 
expr2 = 3*x*Cos[2*x];

SolveAlways[expr1 == expr2, {x, Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}]

(*   {{c3 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c1 -> 3/16, c4 -> 3/8}}   *)

f = -3*c1*Exp[-x] + Cos[x]*(-3*c2 - c3) + Sin[x]*(-3*c3 + c2);
g = Exp[-x] + 2*Cos[x];

SolveAlways[f == g /. Exp[-x] -> ee, {Sin[ x], Cos[ x], ee}]

(*   {{c1 -> -(1/3), c2 -> -(3/5), c3 -> -(1/5)}}   *)
```

May be in cases with equivalent Sin-Cos expressions you should TrigExpand `SolveAlways[expr1 == expr2 // TrigExpand, {x, Sin[ x], Cos[ x]}]`

**Edit**

you can also collect the Sin and Cos and both prefactors have to be zero for equations to be valid for all x.

```
ee = expr1 - expr2 == 0 // Collect[#, {Sin[2 x], Cos[2 x]}] &

(*   (4 c2 + 2 c3 - 3 x + 8 c4 x) Cos[2 x] + 
          (-4 c1 + 2 c4 - 8 c3 x) Sin[2 x] == 0   *)

SolveAlways[{ee[[1, 1, 1]] == 0, ee[[1, 2, 1]] == 0}, x]

(*   {{c3 -> 0, c2 -> 0, c1 -> 3/16, c4 -> 3/8}}   *)
```

**Edit 2**

Yet an other way with the same result: series expansion of Sin, Cos

```
SolveAlways[
  expr1 == expr2 /. {Sin[2 x] -> Series[Sin[2 x], {x, 0, 6}], 
Cos[2 x] -> Series[Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 6}]}, x]
```